# Convert the original tableview to collectionview data cannot be passed

Tags: ios

I want to replace the original tableview with collectionview, the code of the original tableview:

```
 let selectedRow = MarketView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row
```

I'm learning online to change to this code and I get an error:

```
let selectedRow = MarketView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!.first
```

The error shows:
Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath?' to expected argument type 'Int'
This is the complete code as shown in the figure[image]

I just learned to use collectionview, how should I modify it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike `indexPathForSelectedRow` which returns a single index path `indexPathsForSelectedItems` returns an array of index paths

And `row` is not `first`, the collection view equivalent of `row` – as the name of the API implies – is `item`, you have to write `indexPathsForSelectedItems!.first!.item`.

But it's not recommended to force unwrap the objects.  A safer way is

```
guard let selectedRow = MarketView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first?.item else { return }
```